# Derailleur out of alignment after cable snapped

Tags: derailleur, alignment

The front derailleur cable snapped on a friend's bike, she shifted it with her hand to a rideable position, and rode for a few weeks. She asked me for help replacing the cable, though when I replaced it, I realized it couldn't shift the cable onto the big ring, as the derailleur cage touches the inside of the larger chainring, instead of guiding the cable above it. [[EDIT: Touches the chainguard, as pointed out below]].

On visual inspection, it seems like the derailleur is installed too close to the chainring, and should be 1-2mm higher. The thing that seemed obvious to do, but very likely *wrong*, would be to unscrew the derailleur hanger at the frame, lift it 1-2mm, and reclamp it. But this is a 30 year old bike, where the derailleur surely has never been moved. I'm sure I'd be making things worse if I tried this.

Is it possible that the cage is bent somewhere else, and there's another way to adjust it? Photos attached.

[image: Side view]

[image: Top view]

Comment: If your friend needed to move the cage by hand to a rideable position, it might need some oil or spray lube in the pivots for starters. It should spring back to the small ring by default

Comment: Did you mean raise the derailleur by 1-2 *millimeters*, rather than *centimeters*? The cage should actually clear the large chainring by about 2mm.

Comment: unscrew the derailleur hanger at the frame, lift it 1-2mm, and reclamp it

Comment: Surprisingly, the derailleur hanger had fallen slightly. Not that I can tell, but by elimination (the derailleur was perfectly straight to the chain, and not bent), that was the fix.

Comment: Could be there were two problems here.  Some people run their bikes in the middle or little chainring all the time.  I wonder if the cable snapping had nothing much to do with the FD being out of position.

Comment: If the derailleur is sorted, now is the time to ask if those tyres need replacing

Comment: @Criggie - yes, they said they hadn't shifted the chainring since I tested it when we bought the bike. I said they should do it but to be honest I don't have a good reason why. If someone just rides around town, maybe there's no issue with using a single chainring? Still I want to fix it, otherwise it will bug me.

Comment: @Swifty, haha, yes. I initially thought about putting an note about the tires, expecting someone was going to point that out (which is fine, it's a safety issue). Changing the tires was actually the impetus for me fixing the cable, and they've both been replaced. It was amazing, the front tire actually had been torn completely through, exposing about 2mm of tube to the road and they hadn't gotten a flat (the tires also were not very pumped, which helped).

Comment: @lilster that's lucky! If you had already replaced them I think you were best keeping quiet, the thread would have been hijacked by everyone scandalised by the condition of the sidewalls ><

Comment: Presumably that inner chainring isn't as small as newer ones so is pretty good around town. The downside to not using the outer ring is cross-chaining in the smaller cogs, and a tendency for the front mech to seize if it doesn't get exercised. These aren't world ending problems but be prepared for people to have opinions on it...

Comment: @Criggie seems a bit enigmatic... do you mean there's some lurking cause of the snapped cable ready to cause more problems?

Comment: @swifty I'm simply saying the derailleur misalignment may not have been caused by the snapped cable.  Cables flex with use and will eventually snap - EG brifter gear cables should be replaced 1-2 yearly or as soon as shifting deteriorates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derailleur cage is not interfering with the larger chainring, it's hitting the chainguard.

As you say, its unlikely the derailleur slipped down the seat tube a few mm. Seat tube clamp mounts hold on quite tightly, and if they do move you typically are able to see a line on the frame where dirt accumulated next to the clamp. The parallelogram links are pretty robust and don't typically get twisted or bent. The cage itself may get tweaked but you'd see scratches if there had been an impact.

The derailleur might just have rotated around the frame very slightly causing one end of the cage to contact the guard. You'll be able to see if this is the case because the cage will not be parallel to the chainrings.

If the derailleur has not moved I suspect that the cage is actually able to move far enough outboard to shift the chain to the big ring before it hits the chainguard. If it will not shift the chain, moving the derailleur up a millimeter or two so it just clears the guard will probably be just fine.

It's probably worth running through a full front derailleur setup process to make sure you have the limits set correctly. Park Tool has a great web page and video that walks you through the whole process step by step.

https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like good advice. I'll attempt and then mark as solved.